# How can I specify where ckeditor.js is located?

Tags: django, ckeditor

I'm trying to integrate [django-ckeditor](https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor) into my admin forms. I've followed the required documentation but whenever I want to add a new blog post through my CMS the following error occurs:

> [01/Aug/2013 14:21:34] "GET /admin/RehabLog/post/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8608
>
> [01/Aug/2013 14:21:34] "GET /admin/RehabLog/post/add/static/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js HTTP/1.1" 301 0
>
> [01/Aug/2013 14:21:34] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5169
>
> [01/Aug/2013 14:21:34] "GET /admin/RehabLog/post/add/static/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1800

Now ckeditor.js isn't there which leads me to two questions: Where *is* ckeditor.js and how can I tell django where it is?

As requested here are my some settings:

```
MEDIA_URL = '//s3.amazonaws.com/%s/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_ROOT = '/%s/' % DEFAULT_S3_PATH
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(basepath, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
```

Comment: Can you show your settings like STATIC_ROOT at the moment and show the content of your project folder?

Comment: @MagnusGraviti added it as requested.

Comment: I added it too, it doesn't seem to have any kind of effect whatsoever. I have the same problem as the poster. I thought I have a standard STATIC settings with a `static` folder, and that's where the `collectstatic` properly copied the assets into the `ckeditor` subfolder. Everything aligns well, except the web frontend doesn't look into the static.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to [set CKEDITOR_BASEPATH variable](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Specifying_the_Editor_Path) in order to have the library working correctly.

Comment: I tried setting CKEDITOR_BASEPATH in my settings.py but to no avail. I then tried to follow the docs you linked and set CKEDITOR_BASEPATH to complete gibberish in the admin template to test it but it still says 
`"GET /admin/RehabLog/post/add/static/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1800`

Comment: This is a JavaScript variable ;)

Comment: Heh, I know but I tried wrapping it in <script> tags in my template and it still gave that error.

Comment: O.M.G. thanks @oleq `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` is a JS variable. I cannot believe this.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a directory in your application that serves staticfiles. That is where you should put the `ckeditor.js`. Normally the folder is in root of project and is called `static`

It has to be the same folder referred to in the settings file as `STATIC_ROOT` or listed in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. This way you'll just add `{{STATIC_ROOT}}ckeditor.js` to the template to have it served in the html

Comment: After I run collect static it says it should copy the required files to my STATIC_ROOT. I've ran it but there doesn't appear to be any new files?

Comment: I see the `ckeditor` folder in my `static` folder, obviously my STATIC file settings points there, but the django-ckeditor widget still wondering around appending URL to the current form's path and don't look into `static`. I'm amazed why this is not working out of the box. The GitHub page doesn't mention anything about this.